# What is the name of a graph made of k copies of a 4-cycle connected end to end in a chain, possibly with leaves?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Do graphs of the following sort have a specific name? We've been calling them Cactapillars, as they're cacti that look a little like caterpillars (and the name Caterpillar already refers to a different type of graph).  They consist of k 4-cycles connected end to end, with possibly some leaves attached.  If there's not a specific name for this type, do the versions of the graphs without leaves (i.e. just strings of connected 4-cycles) have a name?

[image: Some sample "Cactapillars"]

Comment: I'd call them centipedes !  (but there doesn't seem to be an official name)

Comment: I agree, there probably isn't a name for these yet. Cacterpillar is nice. Centipede is already taken: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Centipede.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are some observations  concerning the enumeration of these graphs
up to  isomorphism. The  OEIS doesn't  seem to have  an entry  for the
count yet so no verification and no error-proof results.
**Preliminary remark.** We will call these *cacterpillar centipedes* 
and refer to them as *centipedes* throughout.

We consider  the skeleton  of the centipede  into which  we substitute
bushels of leaves  and use the **Polya Enumeration  Theorem** to count
these up to isomorphism. Therefore we need the cycle index $Z(Q_n)$ of
the centipede consisting of $n$  copies of a $4$-cycle. (The slots for
the application of PET are the nodes that have degree two.)

The automorphisms of the centiped are generated by a single flip about
a vertical axis  passing through the center and  individual flips that
exchange the top and bottom node of a $4$-cycle.

We now establish  recurrences for the cycle index  constituents of the
two types of automorphisms. The first type $T$ is the flips of the top
and  bottom nodes of  the $4$-cycles  without the  flip of  the entire
centipede that maps left to right. We obtain
$$t_0 = 1, t_1 = \frac{1}{2} (a_1^2 + a_2)
\quad\text{and}\quad
t_n = t_{n-2} \times
\frac{1}{4} (a_1^4 + 2 a_1^2 a_2 + a_2^2).$$
The above does  not account for the two end nodes  which we will treat
at the  end. The second type  $S$ consists of  a left-right exchanging
flip  combined  with individual  flips  of  top  and bottom  nodes  of
$4$-cycles. We obtain
$$s_0 = 1, s_1 = \frac{1}{2} (a_1^2 + a_2)
\quad\text{and}\quad
s_n = s_{n-2} \times
\frac{1}{4} (2 a_2^2 + 2 a_4).$$
Unrolling these  very simple recurrences  and doing the  accounting we
get
$$t_{2n} = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} (a_1^2 + a_2)^{2n}
\quad\text{and}\quad
t_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} (a_1^2 + a_2)^{2n+1}$$
which we may join to produce
$$t_n = \frac{1}{2^n} (a_1^2 + a_2)^n.$$
For $s_n$ we obtain
$$s_{2n} = \frac{1}{2^n} (a_2^2 + a_4)^n
\quad\text{and}\quad
s_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} (a_1^2+a_2) (a_2^2 + a_4)^n.$$

We are now ready to construct the cycle index of the centipede species
$\mathfrak{Q}$ which is given by
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} Z(Q_n)
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n\ge 1} (a_1^2 t_n + a_2 s_n)$$
where we have included the terms for the outer two nodes.

The first term is easy to sum and works out to
$$ - \frac{1}{2} a_1^2 +
\frac{1}{2} a_1^2 \frac{1}{1-(a_1^2+a_2)/2}.$$
The second term yields
$$ - \frac{1}{2} a_2 +
\frac{1}{2} a_2 \frac{1}{1-(a_2^2+a_4)/2} +
\frac{1}{4} a_2 (a_1^2+a_2) \frac{1}{1-(a_2^2+a_4)/2}.$$

This finally yields the equation for the centipede operator
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} Z(Q_n) = -\frac{1}{2} (a_1^2 + a_2) +
\frac{\frac{1}{2} a_1^2}{1-(a_1^2+a_2)/2} +
\frac{\frac{1}{2} a_2 + \frac{1}{4}a_2 (a_1^2+a_2)}{1-(a_2^2+a_4)/2}.$$

We can now substitute into  this operator to obtain various generating
functions. The repertoire  for the bushels always contains  a $z$ term
as it goes into the slot to represent the node to which the leaves are
attached.

The first is
$$\sum_{n\ge   1} Z(Q_n)(z)  =
\frac{z^4}{1-z^2}.$$

This simply represents the fact that there is one centipede when there
are no leaves  (we are not counting the $n+1$  nodes on the horizontal
axis/spine of the centipede since no bushels are being attached there).

Now suppose there is at most one leaf at the outer nodes. This yields
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} Z(Q_n)(z+z^2) =
-{\frac {{z}^{4} \left( {z}^{2}+z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{7}+{z}^{5}-{
z}^{4}+2\,{z}^{3}-1 \right) }{ \left( {z}^{6}+{z}^{2}-1 \right)
 \left( {z}^{3}+z-1 \right) }}.$$

Finally consider that there may be any number of leaves. This gives
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} Z(Q_n)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right) =
{\frac {{z}^{4} \left( {z}^{6}+{z}^{5}-2\,{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}-{z}^{2}+1
 \right) }{ \left( -1+z \right) ^{2} \left( z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{
6}-2\,{z}^{4}-{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{3}-2\,{z}^{2}-z+1
 \right) }}.$$

As pointed out earlier these last two do not yet have OEIS entries.
They are
$$0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 8, 14, 17, 28, 36, 57, 76, 118, 162, 247, 
346, 521,\ldots$$
and
$$0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 6, 10, 22, 37, 73, 124, 233, 404, 743, 1306, 2377,
4221, 7645,\ldots$$

Here is  some Maple code that  can be used to  explore these sequences
and the corresponding cycle indices.

```
with(combinat):

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
        local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

        res := ind;

        polyvars := indets(poly);
        indvars := indets(ind);

        for v in indvars do
            pot := op(1, v);

            subs1 :=
            [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
                 k=1..nops(polyvars))];

            subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

            res := subs(subs2, res);
        od;

        res;
end;

cp_perm_T :=
proc(n)
    if n=0 then return 1 fi;
    if n=1 then return 1/2*(a[1]^2+a[2]) fi;

    1/4*(a[1]^4+2*a[1]^2*a[2]+a[2]^2)*cp_perm_T(n-2);
end;

cp_perm_T_ex :=
proc(n)
    1/2^n*(a[1]^2+a[2])^n;
end;


cp_perm_S :=
proc(n)
    if n=0 then return 1 fi;
    if n=1 then return 1/2*(a[1]^2+a[2]) fi;

    1/4*(2*a[2]^2+2*a[4])*cp_perm_S(n-2);
end;

cp_perm_S_ex :=
proc(n)
    local m;

    m := floor(n/2);

    if type(n, even) then
        1/2^m*(a[2]^2+a[4])^m
    else
        1/2^(m+1)*(a[1]^2+a[2])*(a[2]^2+a[4])^m;
    fi;
end;

cp :=
proc(n)
    option remember;

    expand(1/2*a[1]^2*cp_perm_T(n)+1/2*a[2]*cp_perm_S(n));
end;



cp_gf :=
proc(lv, n)
    option remember;
    local m, gf;

    gf := 0;
    for m to 2*n do
        gf := gf + pet_varinto_cind(lv, cp(m));
    od;

    seq(coeftayl(series(gf, z=0, 2*n+1), z=0, m), m=1..2*n);
end;

cp_gf_closed :=
proc(lv)
    local cind_op;

    cind_op := -1/2*(a[1]^2+a[2]) +
    1/2*a[1]^2/(1-(a[1]^2+a[2])/2) +
    (1/2*a[2] + 1/4*a[2]*(a[1]^2+a[2]))/(1-(a[2]^2+a[4])/2);

    factor(pet_varinto_cind(lv, cind_op));
end;
```

This [MSElink](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85882/on-the-number-of-caterpillars)
enumerates caterpillars up to isomorphism, which is sort of related.

**Addendum.**  The  single $4$-cycle  also  has  a special  rotational
symmetry that brings the upper and  lower slots into the same orbit as
the left  and right end point.  This symmetry is  not being considered
here. It  is not difficult to  subtract the term for  $Z(Q_1)$ that we
have calculated and replace it by $Z(D_4).$